# Javascript, calculator Eval() Error?

Tags: javascript, calculator

Below is my code . . .

```
<div id="calc">

<input id="screen"></div>
<div id="subkeys">
<div  class="btn1">log</div>
<div  class="btn1">ln</div>
<div  class="btn1">(-)</div>
<div  class="btn1">sin</div>
<div  class="btn1">cos</div>
<div  class="btn1">tan</div>
<div  class="btn1">sin<sup>-1</sup></div>
<div  class="btn1">cos<sup>-1</sup></div>
<div  class="btn1">tan<sup>-1</sup></div>
</div>
<div id="mainkeys">
<div name="del" value="" onClick="rundel()" class="btn2 btn-del">DEL</div>
<div name="minus" value="-" onClick="runminus()" class="btn2 btn-minus">-</div>
<div name="multi" value="x" onClick="runmulti()" class="btn2 btn-multi">x</div>
<div name="plus" value="+" onClick="runplus()" class="btn2 btn-plus">+</div>
<div name="1" value="1" onClick="addDigit(1)" class="btn2 num">1</div>
<div name="2" value="2" onClick="addDigit(2)" class="btn2 num">2</div>
<div name="3" value="3" onClick="addDigit(3)" class="btn2 num">3</div>
<div name="div" value="÷" onClick="rundiv()" class="btn2 btn-div">÷</div>
<div name="ans" value="ans" onClick="runans()" class="btn2 btn-ans">ANS</div>
<div name="0" value="0" onClick="addDigit(0)" class="btn2 num">0</div>
<div name="eq" value="=" onClick="runeq()" class="btn2 btn-eq">=</div>
</div>

<script>
function addDigit(digit) {  
document.getElementById('output').value += digit;     
}
function rundel(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runminus(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runplus(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function rundiv(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runmulti(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runeq(){
var result = eval(document.getElementById('output').value = "")
    document.getElementById('output').value = result;
}
</script>
```

When i am trying to add, substract , divide, or mutliply the two numbers the result i am getting is UNDEFINED, i want the result i.e, when i press + key the result should be additions off those keys, how to fix this error . . .

[Here is Link](http://dgcalc.comli.com/)

Comment: change var result = eval(document.getElementById('output').value = "") to result = eval(document.getElementById('output').value)

Comment: ^^ what he said, evaluating setting a value doesn't return what you think it does, and close the last function, fix the syntax errors, add an element with the ID "output" etc ?

Comment: No result, its showing the last character i have pressed . . . @ Shadow

Comment: Yeah id is "output" not "screen" @ adeneo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**eval** is **evil** ... you should try never to use eval.. unless absoultely necessary... 
you can store the last input and current operation  in a variable.. and do the calculations.. but.. this is much harder to maintain than simply using eval...

for example... you can do something like this.. . [jsfiddle demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/HQFxj/1/)

```
var lastInput = 0; //storing last input
var curOp; // current operation.. plus,minus,div etc...

function addDigit(digit) {
    document.getElementById('output').value += digit;
}

function runeq() {
    var result = 0;
    switch (curOp) {
    case "minus":
        result = lastInput - getValue();
        break;
        case "plus" :
                    result = lastInput + getValue();
        break;
        case "div" :
                    result = lastInput / getValue();
        break;      
        case "multi" :
                    result = lastInput * getValue();
         break;
    default:
        result = 0;
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById('output').value = result;
    curOp = 0 ;
    lastInput = getValue();
}

function rundel(){
    lastInput = 0;
curOp = 0 ;
clearScreen();}
function runminus() {
    curOp = "minus";
    lastInput = getValue();
    //for testing.. 
    document.getElementById('test').value = lastInput;
    clearScreen();
}

function runplus() {
    curOp = "plus";
    lastInput = getValue();
    //for testing.. 
    document.getElementById('test').value = lastInput;
    clearScreen();
}

function rundiv() {
    curOp = "div";
    lastInput = getValue();
    //for testing.. 
    document.getElementById('test').value = lastInput;
    clearScreen();
}

function runmulti() {
    curOp = "multi";
    lastInput = getValue();
    //for testing.. 
    document.getElementById('test').value = lastInput;
    clearScreen();
}

function getValue() {
    return parseInt(document.getElementById('output').value,10) ;
}

function clearScreen() {
    document.getElementById('output').value = "";
}
```

Comment: you code is very helpfull, but the only error is, if i am trying to add, sub or mutliply , (for ex. 11+11 = 22) after clicking on '=' sign , if i click on any number it is displaying with the lastInput.. for ex, if i press num 1,  it is displaying like 221

Comment: oh i see.. here is the somehow fixed link... http://jsfiddle.net/HQFxj/2/ and  i told you already "that this is much harder to maintain" ._.

Comment: Thank you, but again there is a bug, there's no repeating of numbers but after 1 calculation, if i press any num it only showing one num, i.e, if i click 22 it's showing only 2

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function addDigit(digit) {  
document.getElementById('output').value += digit;     
}
function rundel(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runminus(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runplus(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function rundiv(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runmulti(){document.getElementById('output').value = "";}
function runeq(){
var result = eval(document.getElementById('output').value);
    document.getElementById('output').value = result;
</script>
```

Try this...

Comment: No result, its showing the last character i have pressed . . .

Comment: can u setup a fiddle n share it??